# when some changes in excel without saving How to read using poi in java

Tags: java

I am having Excel File with list.i am getting the value when i save . how to get the value without saving using poi in java ..

```
                    CellValue c=formulaEval.evaluate(cell);
                    String sFormula = (String) cell.getCellFormula();
                    System.out.println("sFormula "+sFormula);
                   //System.out.println("formula "+c.getNumberValue());

                 //   formulaEval=wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
                    formulaEval.setDebugEvaluationOutputForNextEval(true);
                    System.out.println("formulaEval "+formulaEval.evaluateFormulaCell(cell));
                  // XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(wb);


                    Cell fCellVal=formulaEval.evaluateInCell(cell);

                     System.out.println("fCellVal "+fCellVal);
```

Comment: You need to post more than just a snippet of code. And get what value, without saving what? This problem may better be solved using VBA, anyway.

Comment: We cannot read the changes without saving.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Apache POI works on the byte content of the saved file. It cannot access the Excel runtime and query the current state of unsaved worksheets.

Comment: Hi Markus. Thanks for your feedback. there is some refresh methods for poi to get the value without saving .

Comment: Are you sure? Can you point me to the refresh methods? As far as I know, POI does have refresh methods, but those force Excel to refresh external references and calculations when a spreadsheet is opened, they do not refresh the content that has been read by POI.

Comment: Really Thanks Markus... I got it.